# Is there a way to convert a string to hexadecimal in haxe?

Tags: haxe

I am trying to write a program in Haxe but I got stuck on trying to convert a string to hex. I found a solution but I couldn't get it working. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert a string in hexadecimal format into an integer:

```
final hex = Std.parseInt("0x00");
```

https://api.haxe.org/Std.html#parseInt